# ScrollView not scrolling

Tags: android, scrollview

My `ScrollView` doesn't scroll. When I remove `weightSum` and `layout_weight` it works fine, or if I set height of the `scrollView` to `fixed dip`, but then my layout is all messed up.

If anybody can help me or give me some other solution to how to solve my problem, I'd be very appreciative.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/crni03_pozadina"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2sp"
        android:text="by Crni03"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="100" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvNo"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="50"
                    android:text="@string/tvNo"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvSt"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="50"
                    android:text="@string/tvSt"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="100" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etNo"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="50"
                    android:hint="@string/tvNo"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/etSt"
                    android:nextFocusRight="@+id/etSt"
                    android:textSize="12sp" >

                    <requestFocus />
                </EditText>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etSt"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="50"
                    android:hint="@string/tvSt"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="100" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvKu"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="29"
                    android:text="@string/tvKu"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvOt"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="42"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/tvOt"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvZa"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="29"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="@string/tvZa"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="100" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etKu"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="29"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etOt"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="42"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etZa"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="29"
                    android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bTotal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/bIzracunaj" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bPovratak"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/bPovratak" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etPostotak"
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:text="@string/etCijena5"
                android:textSize="10sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I can't understand the problem. How the layout is messed up? Can you post the snapshot?

Comment: The layout's fine untill i remove weightSum and Layout_weight,b ut then it scrolls. If i leave weightSum and Layout_weight it don't scroll. Setting ScrollView heihgt to fix dip make it scroll, but it don't look right.

Comment: edit:
When my keyboard comes up, ScrollView dont scroll and the keyboard covers a part of the layout, but if the screen size is smaler than the layout, it does scroll. But it only scrolls regarding to the screen size. the keyboard covers the layout as it does on the bigger screen

Comment: got the problem solved. When i removed 
**getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);**
from my.java it works just fine